# XSLT transforming generic nodes to specific nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I've been struggeling to perform a transformation on a document which has identical node names and needs to be split up in specific nodes. Visually you could say it's transforming rows to columns. This is my source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
<Car>
    <Element>
        <Question>Brand</Question>
        <Answer>Ford</Answer>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Question>Year</Question>
        <Answer>1995</Answer>
    </Element>
</Car>
<Car>
    <Element>
        <Question>Brand</Question>
        <Answer>Hummer</Answer>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Question>Year</Question>
        <Answer>1990</Answer>
    </Element>
</Car>
</Document>
```

What I need is the following result:

```
<Document>
    <Car>
        <Brand>Ford</Brand>
        <Year>1995</Year>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Brand>Hummer</Brand>
        <Year>1990</Year>
    </Car>
</Document>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: This is possible, but dangerous: if any question contains a value that's not a valid element name, you will get a fatal error.

Comment: I know what you mean, but that won't be a problem, in the source system the node "Brand" is an actual question which won't change... it's because of poor export possibilities that I need to do this transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is rather trivial, I don't know why you're struggling with it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Document">
    <Document>
        <xsl:for-each select="Car">
            <Car>
                <xsl:for-each select="Element">
                    <xsl:element name="{Question}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Answer" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Car>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That was indeed easier than I thought, thank you very much for this quick response!